# How to give approve and edit permissions without read/write

Tags: list, permissions

So I have a list with a running WF. I have two type of users, first has edit/read permissions others must have approve and add their comments only.

I want the second type to be able to approve but not see the full content of the list `/Lists/listname/allitems.aspx`

How to make `/Lists/listname/allitems.aspx`  only visible to the first type of users?

Answer (score 1):

Alas *Approve* is extra rights on top op *Write* rights.

You could work around it by creating an extra list where you create stubs for all items that need to be approved.
Once Approved the item in the original list is approved using a Workflow with elevated permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Not a recommended approach, but you can use item level permissions and remove rights of user type 2 on all the items which you want to hide from them. 
To be more efficient, break permissions for the items where they should see!